# Is the ContentBodyId the ContentPack Id on ContentVersion Object

Tags: files, content

Is the ContentBodyId the ContentPack id/reference on the ContentVersion Object?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

The official docs, list some verbage that is unclear to me.

"*Allows inserting a file version independently of the file blob being uploaded. This field is available for query and insert only. It can only point to a ContentBody record. This field is available in API version 40.0 and later.*"

It is a reference field, seems logical to be the Content Pack (body itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contentbody represents the body of a file in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files. ContentBody is intended for internal Salesforce use. If you need to access the file content body, use ContentVersion.

To view all the content, query `[SELECT Id,Title FROM ContentVersion]` to get the Id of the dcoument and copy the Id in the salesforce url. You also can navigate to the Content tab in Salesforce to view all the content.

You can query Content Packs using `SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE FileType = 'PACK'`.